# Is there any way to reload or refresh a data table data?

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatables

I have a problem about data tables which is duplication of data rows when triggering a button that refresh the data table datas. I tried some code like 
$("#table").ajax.reload(); and $("#table").empty(); but non of those solve my problem

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Dashboard/LatestCheckin'); ?>",
            data: {},
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                result = JSON.parse(data);
            var table = $('#latest-checkin-table').DataTable();  


            if(result!='') {        

                $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                  var a =  table.row.add([
          result[i].count 
          ,result[i].full_name 
          ,result[i].room_no 
          ,result[i].total_price 
          ,result[i].checkin_date
                    ]).draw();
                });    

            } else {
                $('#latest-checkin-table').html('<h3>No users are available</h3>');
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
table.clear();
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
                  var a =  table.row.add([
          result[i].count 
          ,result[i].full_name 
          ,result[i].room_no 
          ,result[i].total_price 
          ,result[i].checkin_date
                    ]);
                });
table.draw();
```

hope it helps.

Comment: THANKS A LOT IT WORKS NOW HEHEHE . :D

Comment: @Noodles You bet.